# How to add classes when clicking React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tell me how, when clicked, add a class to an element, and delete it from everyone else?

```
<Menu.ItemGroup key="g1" title={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.logoMenu()}></div>}>
                        <Menu.Item key="1" icon={<HomeOutlined/>} className="ant-menu-item-selected"><a href="/">1</a></Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<BookOutlined/>}><a href="/home">2</a></Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item key="3" icon={<AppstoreOutlined/>}><a href="/test">3</a></Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item key="4" icon={<SearchOutlined/>}><a href="/search">4</a></Menu.Item>
                    </Menu.ItemGroup>
```

Comment: In the code that you posted, which element would you like to add the class to, and which ones would you like to remove it from?

Comment: I want to add to the one I click on (1,2,3,4) and remove from all the others

Comment: Ok, if you add the code for your Menu.ItemGroup component to your question like I can give you a way to implement that.

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing this, so I assume you're in a class component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  HomeOutlined,
  BookOutlined,
  AppstoreOutlined,
  SearchOutlined
} from 'icons'

const TitleComponent = ({ title }) => <div>{title}</div>

class YourMenuComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // set your first item as default
      // this gets replaced with whichever item you want to make current
      activeItem: 1
    }

    // this really should be coming through props,
    // or imported as a menuitem.js file
    // By creating your menu items and array of objects you can iterate
    // through each item and create your menu item output
    // key and title are different, assuming you're wanting
    // unique keys and titles may end up being strings
    // (if your menu item titles are unique, you could use those)

    this.menuItems = [
      { title: 1, url: '/', key: 1, icon: HomeOutlined },
      { title: 2, url: '/home', key: 2, icon: BookOutlined },
      { title: 3, url: '/test', key: 3, icon: AppstoreOutlined },
      { title: 4, url: '/search', key: 4, icon: SearchOutlined }
    ]
  }

  // not sure what this looks like, so I'm just shooting a blank
  logoMenu = () => 'some title'

  // this function pushes the current active item to state,
  // and replaces the previous one
  setActiveItem = key => this.setState({ activeItem: key })

  render() {
    const TitleComp = <TitleComponent title={this.logoMenu()} />

    return (

      // you probably want to avoid passing components like
      // this <comp /> and pass them as variables instead
      // small refactor
      <Menu.ItemGroup key="g1" title={TitleComp}>
        {this.menuItems.map(item => (
          <Menu.Item
            key={item.key}
            icon={item.icon}

            // set className on the active item only,
            // and set empty string on inactive items
            className={
              this.state.activeItem === item.key ? 'ant-menu-item-selected' : ''
            }

            // use the current items key to set it as active when clicked
            onClick={() => this.setActiveItem(item.key)}
          >
            <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
          </Menu.Item>
        ))}
      </Menu.ItemGroup>
    )
  }
}

export default YourMenuComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to store state which can represent if an item is selected. You could also store a class name in state.

```
const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState('1');

function updateSelection(item) {
  setItemSelected(item)
}

<div
  onClick={() => setItemSelected('1')}
  className={`itemSelected == 1 ? 'selected' : ''`}>
  1
</div>
<div
  onClick={() => setItemSelected('2')}
  className={`itemSelected == 2 ? 'selected' : ''`}>
  2
</div>
<div
  onClick={() => setItemSelected('3')}
  className={`itemSelected == 3 ? 'selected' : ''`}>
  3
</div>
```